# How find all SIMILAR substrings between two strings

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have tow strings :

> 1. "NortonAPPLEKooKoo"
> 2. "kooappHelloNort"

Now **SIMILAR** substrings between two those strings are (**Ignore Case**) :

> "a"     ...     "koo"   "app"   "nort"

How can i write a method in c# to handle that job?

My goal is to find the biggest length of result array, here is :

> "nort"

Comment: This is a well-studied problem. Research the longest common substring problem.

Comment: To find substrings that are similar (but not identical), I would use an [approximate string matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
   var string1 = "NortonAPPLEKooKoo";
   var string2 = "kooappHelloNort";

   var substrings =
        from start in Enumerable.Range(0, string1.Length)
        from end in Enumerable.Range(0, string1.Length - start + 1)
        select string1.Substring(start, end);

   var matching = substrings.Where(item => string2.Contains(item));

   var longest = matching.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First();
```

`substrings` contains all the possible substrings of `string1`.

`matching` contains all the substrings that also exist in `string2`.

`longest` will be the longest substring that exists in `string2` which in your example will be 'nort'.

Comment: This is insanely inefficient if the strings are long. Build a suffix tree instead.

Comment: Agreed, however Implementing a suffix tree is complex and not required if the strings are short.